# Alert ok button event in Ruby

Tags: ruby, click, alert, rhomobile, rhodes

I am creating a Rhodes cross platform application. Somewhere in my application I am displaying an Alert with a default OK button. This is my code :

```
Alert.show_popup "Payment successful. Your Transaction Number :  "+$payment["transactionid"].to_s
WebView.navigate ( url_for :controller => :Categories, :action => :index )
```

What actually happens is I am displaying Alert as well as navigating simultaneously. But what I want is to navigate only when I click that OK button on the Alert.

Comment: Nitish, for somebody with quite a bit of SO reputation, that's a rather bad question. What have you tried already, where did you have problems etc?

Comment: @MichaelKohl : :) Actually I am new to Ruby development. Basically I am into IPhone development. I was just not able to figure out how to capture OK button event for Alert. Yes my question could had been better.

Comment: Well, you still didn't show us any code you already tried and where exactly your problem lies. But this sounds like it's more of JS problem than a Ruby one.

Comment: You need to provide many more details. What is the context? A web application? A GUI application?

Comment: @MichaelKohl & Carl : I have edited my question. Please see

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rhodes, but added the appropriate tags so people in the know are able to find your question.

Comment: Got the answer [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#alerts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a callback function, where you would perform the navigation. Try something like:

```
Alert.show_popup(:message => "Payment successful. Your Transaction Number : "+$payment["transactionid"].to_s, 
                :callback => :go_to_categories_cb)
```

And in the same module define the callback method:

```
def go_to_categories_cb
    WebView.navigate ( url_for :controller => :Categories, :action => :index )
end
```